How to import in a directory other than main directory in a python project
I am structuring a python project including two directories as the following tree.

In first directory, I have a module and init.py. The content of init module is
from .module1 import func1

In the second directory, I am importing func1 as below.
from dir1 import func1

But, the following error occurs.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir1'

How to solve this problem?
I run the func2 in the main directory and I worked well. However, I need it to work in dir2.

Not a git question (nor github)

Try from dir1.module import func1

Please provide the tree structure of your 2 directories.

I added the tree to my question. @LoukasPap

Try Try from dir1.module import func1
It would be better to add init.py in dir2 too

from dir1.module import func1

I did but does not work yet
